# Managing OpenVZ containers with Ansible

Tags: openvz, ansible

Is there any elegant way to manipulate OpenVZ containers with Ansible?
Sure I can install an SSH daemon on each and put my public keys, but as soon as there is a `vzcl enter` command maybe there is a possibility to use it somehow?
I've searched the Internet for any Ansible roles and modules allowing to do that, but there are only ones for setting up the OpenVZ node itself.

Also it would be quite cool if I could restart containers, destroy then and so on.

Answer (score 3):

I'm developing [openvzmod](https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/3900), yet another role with modules to manage OpenVZ containers.  Please give it a try and drop me a line at [the issue tracker](https://github.com/yaegashi/ansible-role-openvzmod/issues) if you have any comments.